# Provide title to each of the subplots - R Shiny

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I am trying to create plots using the following code from @blondeclover. The code is as follows -

```html
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(grid)

shinyApp(
    ##### ui #######
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            sliderInput("n", 
                        "Number of plots", 
                        value = 1, min = 1, max = 5)),
        fluidRow(
            plotlyOutput("plots")
        )
    ), 
    ##### server ######
    server = function(input, output) {
        data("cars")
        # define max number of plots
        max_plots <- 5
        # generate the plots
        output$plots <- renderPlotly({
            plot_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
                g <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
                    geom_point() +
                    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 1, 1, 1), "lines"))
                ggplotly(g)
            })
            p <- subplot(plot_list[1:input$n], shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE) %>%
                layout(title = "Car Plots")
            dev.off()
            p
        })
    }
)
```

However, I am unable to bring up the title of each subplots I receive as output. My plot's title varies via a parameter. So, I want to display it as title. How to render title for each plot instead of a single title for all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. We need to use `facet_wrap` instead of `ggtitle` in the ggplot code. Posting it here, so that it would be useful for anyone who stumble on the same issue as mine. Code is as follows:

```html
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(grid)

shinyApp(
    ##### ui #######
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            sliderInput("n", 
                        "Number of plots", 
                        value = 1, min = 1, max = 5)),
        fluidRow(
            plotlyOutput("plots")
        )
    ), 
    ##### server ######
    server = function(input, output) {
        data("cars")
        # define max number of plots
        max_plots <- 5
        cars$main1 <- "title"
        # generate the plots
        output$plots <- renderPlotly({
            plot_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
                g <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
                    geom_point() + 
                    facet_wrap(~main1) +
                    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3, 1, 1, 1), "lines"))
                ggplotly(g)
            })
            p <- subplot(plot_list[1:input$n], shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
            dev.off()
            p
        })
    }
)
```