# Formatting Shiny Plotly subplots - Individual titles and graph size

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to provide individual titles for each of my graphs within `plotly`'s `subplot` function and I found a post where you can extend subplot using `%>% layout(title = "Main Title)` but I'd like individual titles for each graph (I'm using `ggtitle` but that only plots the last title provided (Plot 4). I found a similar post [Provide title to each of the subplots - R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412355/provide-title-to-each-of-the-subplots-r-shiny) but I don't think that I can `facet_wrap` in my scenario.

Furthermore - I was wondering how to increase the margin between the graphs in a subplot since they seemed to be really squished together.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel("This is a sidebar"),
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("myplot"))
    )

server <- function(input, output){

  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({

    gg1 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
        geom_point() +
        theme_minimal() +
        ggtitle("Plot 1")
    )

    gg2 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        theme_minimal() +
        ggtitle("Plot 2")
    )

    gg3 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width)) +
        geom_histogram() +
        ggtitle("Plot 3")
    )

    gg4 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length)) +
        geom_histogram() +
        ggtitle("Plot 4")
    )

    subplot(list(gg1,gg2,gg3,gg4), nrows = 2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285729/how-to-give-subtitles-for-subplot-in-plot-ly-using-r

you can't set a title for each graph.. you can use `annotation` which gets the work done somehow..

Do you need to keep all 4 graphs together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Edo subplot titles are an [open issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/660) regarding R's plotly api. Currently we need to use annotations. Here is an [official example](https://plot.ly/~PlotBot/922/multiple-subplots-with-titles/#plot).

The `subplot` function provides us with an argument `margin` to add some space.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel("This is a sidebar"),
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("myplot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({

    gg1 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
        geom_point() +
        theme_minimal()
    ) %>% add_annotations(
      text = "Plot 1",
      x = 0,
      y = 1,
      yref = "paper",
      xref = "paper",
      xanchor = "left",
      yanchor = "top",
      yshift = 20,
      showarrow = FALSE,
      font = list(size = 15)
    )

    gg2 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        theme_minimal()
    ) %>% add_annotations(
      text = "Plot 2",
      x = 0,
      y = 1,
      yref = "paper",
      xref = "paper",
      xanchor = "left",
      yanchor = "top",
      yshift = 20,
      showarrow = FALSE,
      font = list(size = 15)
    )

    gg3 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width)) +
        geom_histogram()
    ) %>% add_annotations(
      text = "Plot 3",
      x = 0,
      y = 1,
      yref = "paper",
      xref = "paper",
      xanchor = "left",
      yanchor = "top",
      yshift = 20,
      showarrow = FALSE,
      font = list(size = 15)
    )

    gg4 <- ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length)) +
        geom_histogram()
    ) %>% add_annotations(
      text = "Plot 4",
      x = 0,
      y = 1,
      yref = "paper",
      xref = "paper",
      xanchor = "left",
      yanchor = "top",
      yshift = 20,
      showarrow = FALSE,
      font = list(size = 15)
    )

    subplot(list(gg1,gg2,gg3,gg4), nrows = 2, margin = 0.06)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Result]

By the way you can use `schema()` to browse through plotly's attributes.